# Click on angular-mentions is not working inside angular-editor

Tags: javascript, angular, rich-text-editor

I'm using "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^1.1.2" together with "angular-mentions": "^1.2.0" in an "@angular/core": "^10.1.4" project.

I'm triggering the mentions using the '@' character, and I can navigate throw the options with the arrows, and select with Enter; but if I try to click an option, the mentions list immediately closes.

What I noticed so far:

1. When clicking an option, two `blur` events occur, followed by two `focus` events. Using `preventDefault()` or `stopPropagation()` inside the callback functions did not make any difference.
2. I tried upgrading or downgrading the packages, but it also made no difference;
3. Looked over this GitHub question https://github.com/dmacfarlane/angular-mentions/issues/185 but could not find the `nativeElement.focus()` inside the source files in order to edit them; which I'd rather avoid if possible.
4. The angular-mentions work as expected inside a `<textarea>` or `<input>` element. Only inside the angular-editor there seems to be some event conflict.

TL;DR Why can't I select mentions inside angular-editor using click?

[image]